# WooCommerce get_price_html

Tags: wordpress, format, woocommerce, currency

First of all I searched through the site to find relevant topics before askig this question and didn't find what I needed, maybe my search terms were not relevant, I don't know. Sorry if this is asked and answered before.

Anyway, by default, WooCommerce shows the pricings with this format : "currency" "price" like "$ 25".
All I want to do is pretty simple, I just want to switch their places so what is shown to users will be like : "price" "currency" as in "25 $".

That's quite simple, I know, but since I'm totally new to WooCommerce and its functions I couldn't find it on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an hard one to find in WooCommerce.

You don't need to change it in core functionality.

You can change it from Settings Page.

I believe you are having latest woocommerce version.

I am having Version 2.1.12.

Go to **WooCommerce Menu** => **Settings Sub Menu** => **General Tab**

Under **Currency Options**, You will have the option of Currency Position where you can change the option.

Comment: I proved to be a rookie :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In an additional note, if you want more options when you are editing WooCommerce templates, get_price() will give you the plain value. You can then wrap this up in whatever html you like.